# Proof that a sequence is not Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

I've got this sequence :

$$a_n=1+ \sum_{k=2}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\ln k} $$

It is obvious that this sequence is not a Cauchy sequence but I cannot understand how i can prove it.

I know that a sequence is not Cauchy if there exists an  $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $m,n>N$ such that $|x_{m}-x_{n}|\geq\varepsilon$.

Any answer will be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot say in the same sentence that something is obvious and that you have no clue how to explain it. Why is it obvious?

Comment: It is obvious that this is not a cauchy sequence since the sequence will continue to increase and the elements will not become closer to each other as the sequence progresses

Comment: How is the situation that you just described different from $a_n=\sum_{k=2}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ which *is* a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Yeah ... i didnt write it correctly i am sorry i will edit it right now.
But even if i didnt write it correctly can you please send me the link to the proof of your sequence ? That you said that it is cauchy ?

Comment: I don't have a link. It is obvious :-) It is Cauchy because it converges.

Comment: $|a_{2^{n+1}}-a_{2^n}|\geq 2^{n}\frac{1}{\ln(2^{n+1})}=\frac{2^n}{n+1}\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\to\infty$, where the inequality is obtained by replacing all terms by the last one, which is the smaller.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier hahahaha good one , thank you

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thank you!